# How do I prove that the vertex chromatic number of a subgraph is less than that of the original graph?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

How do I prove that the vertex chromatic number of a subgraph is less than that of the original graph? Say I have a graph with chromatic number $k$. How do I prove that the chromatic number any subgraph is less than $k$?

Comment: Less than or equal to

Comment: @Anon E. Muss: Do you have a specific graph in mind? What is the subgraph? Any examples or exercises?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let C be a k-coloring of the graph. You can reduce it to a vertex coloring of a subgraph (by simply using the same colors). So the chromatic number of the subgraph is less than or equal to k.